# How to insert,update and delete in entity framework using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm now learning about entity framework. Most of my sql queries are raw sql queries. I was advised to use entity framework instead and I want to convert every raw sql query that i have into entity framework. As of now, i am able to convert the regular select statement that we use like this:

```
SELECT * from brand
```

into this:

```
list = (from g in obj.brands select g).ToList();
```

Now, i wanted to know how to insert,update and delete using entity framework in asp.net. My question is, what is the equivalent entity framework query of the following raw sql queries that i have provided below? Also is there sql parameters in entity framework?

1.) `DELETE S FROM stringInstrumentItem S JOIN brand B ON S.brandId = B.brandId WHERE B.name = @brand`

2.) `UPDATE [brand] SET type = @type, name = @name, image = @image WHERE brandId = @brandId`

3.) `UPDATE SII SET SII.brandId = b.brandId FROM stringInstrumentItem SII inner join brand b ON SII.brandId = b.brandId AND b.name = @newName`

4.) `INSERT INTO brand VALUES (@brandId,@type,@name,@image)`

Comment: What have you tried yourself? After searching google checkout the links https://www.google.nl/search?q=crud+in+entity+framework&oq=CRUD+in+Entit&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.8422j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score -2):

Some query no available in EF, look to http://entityframework-extensions.net